# jQuery events doesn't work with html tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

html tag in javascript:

```
var html="<div><a class='link' href='#'>Click</a></div>;
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#html").html(html);
   $(".link").click(do something);
});
```

html

```
<html>
    <div id="html"></div>
 </html>`
```

Why does jQuery not work when I do it this way, I tried with functions and event in html tags, it works!

Comment: Isn't there a typo in your var declaration? string is not ended with `"`

Comment: Where exactly is that JavaScript code located if that really is all the HTML you've got?

Answer (score 0):

```
var html="<div><a class='link' href='#'>Click</a></div>";
```

^^^ missing the closing "

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a callback function to the `.click()` method, like so:

```
$(".link").click(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing your closing `"` on the `html` line.

If that was a typo you made putting your code on Stack Overflow, be sure your `html` variable has its value *before* the `onload` event:

```
var html="<div><a class='link' href='#'>Click</a></div>";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#html").html(html);
    $(".link").click();
});
```

Also, if you were wanting the "do something" to actually execute code, you need to setup an event handler for the `click` event:

```
$(".link").click(function() {
    alert('The link was clicked.');
});
```

Comment: Okay, so I saw in [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/y6z3j/) that it's working. So... is your question answered? If so, you should accept the answer that best helped you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's working: http://jsfiddle.net/y6z3j/

Comment: even this is working:
http://jsfiddle.net/xTpHU/1/

and why do you want to set focus on an hidden field??